# ul not aligned properly in IE7 - Aligned to the right of the div, aligned to the left in every other browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

So I'm making an auto-complete dropdown list, using javascript.  It works fine in IE8+, Chrome, and Firefox, but the alignment is off in IE7.

Here's how it's [supposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRPYq.jpg) to look, and here's how it [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiJdu.jpg) in IE7.  I've uploaded the HTML [here](http://pastehtml.com/view/bak6zgewi.html).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `left: 0;` to `.autocomplete_completionListElement` — you have an absolute positioning here and IE thinks that it still must be on a line with previous content, so you need to set `left` to make IE know where the div must be positioned for sure.